# Does Bigquery save a timestamp with every row inserted through streaming?

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that Hbase saves a timestamp with every insert. Is it the same in google BigQuery? How can you access it?

Answer (score 11):

For now the workaround exists:

"This feature is already in the production in a different way. If user want to save a timestamp when a request reaching the BigQuery stream system, user could add a TIMESTAMP column in the table schema, and assign "AUTO" in your json payload. With "AUTO" key words, the system will set the column value to be the wall timestamp on behalf of the user. Hope this helps for your use case."

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72080883#comment19

Comment: Confirming it works, sending over the string "AUTO" (must be capitalized, lower case does not work).

Answer (score 5):

No, BigQuery does not save a timestamp along with the row.

If this is something you'd like to see added, you can file a feature request in BigQuery issue tracker here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list.

Comment: Ok, then how are you able to query based on table decorators (with timestamp)?

Comment: That's a good point, when we buffer the data we store the timestamp; however, when we flush the buffer to disk we lose the fine-grained timestamp information.

Comment: Does that mean that table decorator can cause missing or duplication to query results? We rely on decorator to do incremental data summary, how do we know when and which data is flushed into disk or not?

Comment: Just created a feature request to add the timestamp to BigQuery streaming: https://issuetracker.google.com/72080883

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define default values for columns in your tables.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values

```sql
CREATE TABLE mydataset.mytable (
  x TIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME(),
  y INT64 DEFAULT 5,
  z BOOL);

INSERT mydataset.mytable (x, y, z) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

The table `mytable` looks like the following:

```
+-----------------+---+------+
| x               | y | z    |
+-----------------+---+------+
| 22:13:24.799555 | 5 | null |
+-----------------+---+------+
```

Comment: not helpful at all. It does not answer question