# SQL data cleaning SELECT DISTINCT from duplicate ID and return list of records. Scenario: Return unique IDs for first and latest instance

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates, distinct, data-cleaning

```
Dataset: customer_data
Table: customer_table (30 records)
Fields: customer_id, name
Datatype: customer_id = INTEGER, name = STRING
```

The problem or request: the `customer_table` contains 30 rows of customer data. However, there are some duplicate rows and I need to clean the data. I am using Google BigQuery to perform my SQL querying and I want to query the `customer_table` from the `customer_data` dataset to return unique `customer_id` along with the corresponding `name`.

If duplicate `customer_id` exists, but the duplicate has a different `name`, return the first instance record and discard the duplicate and continue returning all unique `customer_id` and `name`.

Alternately, if duplicate `customer_id` exists, but has different `name`, return the latest instance record from the table and discard the duplicate and continue returning all unique `customer_id` and `name`.

My methods:

1. Identify the unique values using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM customer_data.customer_table
```

Result: 24 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM customer_data.customer_table
```

Result: 25 rows

After finding out the number of unique values from `customer_id` and `name` do not match, I suspect one of the `customer_id` shares two different `name`.

2. Visualize which duplicate `customer_id` has two names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, name
FROM customer_data.customer_table
ORDER BY customer_id ASC
```

Result: 25 rows

It appears there is one duplicate `customer_id` and the same `customer_id` has two different `name`.

Example:

| customer_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1890 | Henry Fiction |
| 1890 | Arthur Stories |

3. Return `DISTINCT` `customer_id` and `name`. If there are duplicates return only the first, discard the duplicate, and continue returning unique `customer_id` and `name`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         customer_id, name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                            ORDER BY customer_id ASC) AS row_num
     FROM
         customer_data.customer_table) subquery
WHERE
    subquery.rownum = 1
```

Result: 24 rows

I decided to try using `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to ask the query to perform an inner task first by making an index for the number of times the query count for each `customer_id`. Then, have it perform the final task with a WHERE clause to return a list of `DISTINCT customer_id` and the matching `name` for the first instance the `customer_id` is recorded in the `customer_table`.

Excellent! I was able to make a query to return unique `customer_id` along with their `name` from the `customer_table`, and if there are duplicate `customer_id` but the duplicate id has different `name`, create a list of `customer_id` and `name` that selects the first instance `customer_id` is recorded in the `customer_table`.

Now, what if I wanted to ask the query to create a list of unique **customer_id** and **name** that, instead of selecting the first **customer_id** when it encounter duplicates, select the latest record entry in the table if it encounter duplicate **customer_id**. How should I approach to solving this problem? What query method would you suggest?

Expected result: 24 rows

What I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, name
FROM
    (SELECT
         customer_id, name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                            ORDER BY customer_id ASC) AS row_num
     FROM
         customer_data.customer_table) subquery
WHERE
    subquery.row_num > 1
```

Result : 4 rows

Desired result: 24 rows

I tried changing the `WHERE` clause for `subquery.row_num > 1` just to see what would change and see the desired values I want in my created list of unique `customer_id` and `name`. Of the 4 rows produced from the query, only one row has the duplicate `customer_id` and different `name` that I want, which is the latest duplicate `customer_id` having a different `name` in the `customer_table`. Referring back to the example where

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, name 
FROM customer_data.customer_table
```

revealed:

| customer_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1890 | Henry Fiction |
| 1890 | Arthur Stories |

One of the duplicates `customer_id`, 1890, was recorded first in the table and the other recorded later. The alternate request is to return a list of unique `customer_id` and `name` that if the query encounters duplicate `customer_id` it will select the latest record in the `customer_table`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have a timestamp when a record was added, I am afraid you won't be able to identify the latest record. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682358/does-bigquery-save-a-timestamp-with-every-row-inserted-through-streaming), BQ does not add the timestamp automatically. Is your table partitioned? If yes, then you might be able to identify the latest record using partitions.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. My table is not partitioned. After taking some time thinking about your answer, I think this is an acceptable answer. Although I was able to fulfill the first request by assuming each row is the order of entry, a field like timestamps would've allowed me to create a query to select the latest record.